# Can't update one colunn in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I don't understand why I can't update one column.
I have query

```
$db->setQuery("update #__cars set pro_cars='$itatit' where id='$id'");
```

It updates fine.
If I want to update another column (pro_cars_it) in the same table it doesn't work.

```
$db->setQuery("update #__cars set pro_cars_it='$itatit' where id='$id'");
```

I don't have idea why is that.
I tried to do both columns at the same time and it's only one table pro_cars updated in the same query.

```
$db->setQuery("update #__cars set pro_cars='$engtit', pro_cars_it='$itatit' where id='$id'");
```

Strange. Any idea?

Comment: Is `#__cars` your actual table name?

Comment: provide table structure of #__Cars... also is pro_cars_it varchar or numeric?

Comment: I already checked. Both are the same (pro_name varchar(255) utf8_general_ci  Yes  NULL)

Comment: Run the query directly on mysql server with the php variable values only and see what happens

Comment: Yes, #__cars is the table name.

Comment: You need to escape the table name in that case. Use back-ticks. You should also consider only using alphanumerical characters, and underscores in your table/column names. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html `Permitted characters in unquoted identifiers: ASCII: [0-9,a-z,A-Z$_] (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)`

Comment: It works directly on mysql server. Unbelievable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks)

Comment: Depending on how those variables are set you also might be open to SQL injections. You should look into prepared statements.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? In SQL-Server, table names beginning with `#` are temporary tables.